# Can a rocket travelling in free space really travel arbitrarily far, with fixed fuel, by slowing down the rate of emission? Intuition vs calculation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$So for A-level physics we were given some very basic Newton's third law rocket thrust questions. I noticed that one of the formulae involved the natural log, and I reverse engineered this formula with integration. Taking it a step further, I came up with an expression for the total distance travelled by a rocket, travelling in a straight line in free space, and the expression is rather... odd. My intuition tells me it is wrong but my integration + a numerical verification suggests it is correct, so I am turning to this forum for a sanity check - it is likely I am overlooking some fundamental principle.

The situation is as follows:

> A rocket is in vacuum, travelling in free space. It has a gas propulsion system; gas is emitted at a constant nonzero rate of $r\,\rm{kg\,s^{-1}}$ and at a nonzero speed $v_g\,\rm{ms^{-1}}$ from the back of the rocket. There is an initial mass of the rocket, $M_r\,\rm{kg}$, and a mass $0\lt M_g\lt M_r$ of gas to be used as fuel.
>
> The thrust experienced by the rocket is $r\cdot v_g\,\rm{N}$, which will be constant throughout the journey. Supposing its initial velocity in the direction of travel, which is straight and constant, is $v_0$. Treating its initial displacement as $0$, how far it travel once it has burnt all of its fuel?

This is not a homework - the question and phrasing is all from my own curiosity. Firstly, after a given time $t$, we want to know by how much the rocket has gained velocity. From $v=\int a\,\d t$, we note that if $m_g$ is the mass of gas burnt thus far, $t=m_g/r$ and the acceleration on the rocket at time $0\le t'\le t$ is $r\cdot v_g/(M_r-rt')$ from Newton's laws. Then:

$$v(t)=v_0+\int_0^{m_g/r}\frac{r\cdot v_g}{M_r-rt}\,\d t=v_0-v_g\left[\ln(M_r-rt)\right]^{m_g/r}_0=v_0+v_g\cdot\ln\left(\frac{M_r}{M_r-m_g}\right)$$

Which agrees with the formula presented to us (without comment) in class. Pursuing this train of thought, the displacement along the direction of travel is given by $s=\int v\,\d t$, a one-dimensional integral as we travel in a straight line in free space; letting $t=m_g/r$ as before, we find:

$$\begin{align}s(t)&=\frac{m_g}{r}\cdot(v_0+v_g\cdot\ln(M_r))-v_g\int_0^{m_g/r}\ln(M_r-rt)\,\d t\\&=\frac{m_g}{r}\cdot(v_0+v_g\cdot\ln(M_r))+\frac{v_g}{r}[(M_r-rt)\ln(M_r-rt)+rt-M_r]^{m_g/r}_0\\&=\frac{m_g}{r}\cdot(v_0+v_g\cdot\ln(M_r))+\frac{v_g}{r}[(M_r-m_g)\ln(M_r-m_g)+m_g-M_r\ln(M_r)]\\&=\frac{m_g}{r}\cdot(v_0+v_g)+\frac{v_g}{r}(M_r-m_g)\ln\left(\frac{M_r-m_g}{M_r}\right)\\&=\color{red}{\frac{1}{r}}\cdot\left\{m_g(v_0+v_g)+v_g(M_r-m_g)\ln\left(\frac{M_r-m_g}{M_r}\right)\right\}\end{align}$$

So, after all its fuel has been spent, the rocket has travelled through a displacement of:

$$s=\frac{1}{r}\cdot\left\{M_g(v_0+v_g)+v_g(M_r-M_g)\ln\left(\frac{M_r-M_g}{M_r}\right)\right\}$$

I have two questions:

1. Is this formula physically accurate, assuming motion in free space, constant rate etc. etc.? Or did I make a logical misstep?
2. The formula implies that if you release the gas really slowly, you will travel arbitrarily far, albeit very slowly. It seems counter-intuitive to me that for a set rocket mass and finite amount of fuel, you can travel *indefinitely*, dare I say infinitely far, by controlling the rate of emission. Does this violate any laws, or is this actually ok since one can never physically attain this limit?

Side-note: inspecting the velocity formula reveals that if the vehicle were somehow pure engine-and-fuel-canister, you could travel indefinitely fast by burning an $M_g$ arbitrarily close to $M_r$. For a finite speed limit like the speed of light, for finite $v_0,v_g,M_r$ it is actually entirely possible (according to the formula) to burn $M_g$ kilograms of fuel sufficiently close to $M_r$ to exceed lightspeed :) There is definitely something a bit fishy with these formulae, a hidden assumption I'm overlooking.

Comment: Notice how, if you start with a velocity $v_0$, just emitting no fuel at all will also get you arbitrarily far. So the result is not that surprising.

Comment: How did you derive the expression $r\cdot v_g/(M_r-rt')$ for the acceleration? Newton's second law states that $F=r\cdot v_g=dp/dt=v(t)dm(t)/dt+m(t)+dv(t)/dt$, but it seems to me that the term containing the derivative of the mass is missing

Comment: @KarimChahine That'd be a problem! Amusingly then the formula provided by my textbook is incorrect, since it made the same false assumption $a=F/m$ that I did

Comment: Also yeah as @noah said in free space any initial velocity will get you arbitrarily far, that's not a problem.